# Why does Option extend Product?

Tags: scala, scala-option

I must be missing something, but I don't see the implementation of `productElement` and `productArity` of the [`Product`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0/src/library/scala/Product.scala#L1) trait in the [`Option`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L1) class.

So two questions:

1. Why would `Option` extend `Product`?
2. How can it be that `Option` (or any of it's two subclasses) is not implementing the two methods?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you generate an `Option` in scala you are actually generating a `Some` or a `None` which are both case classes/objects. The scala compiler does it's magic with case classes and generates `Product` methods for them.

From Scala 2.10 Product.scala:

```
/** Base trait for all products, which in the standard library include at
 *  least [[scala.Product1]] through [[scala.Product22]] and therefore also
 *  their subclasses [[scala.Tuple1]] through [[scala.Tuple22]].  In addition,
 *  all case classes implement `Product` with synthetically generated methods.
 *
 *  @author  Burak Emir
 *  @version 1.0
 *  @since   2.3
 */
```

I hope that answers both your questions, compiler magic!